# General answer of $(\mathbf{x}_n - \boldsymbol{\mu}_k)^\top \boldsymbol{\Lambda}_k(\mathbf{x}_n - \boldsymbol{\mu}_k)$

Tags: matrices

Can we say this generally? 
$$(\mathbf{x}_n - \boldsymbol{\mu}_k)^\top \boldsymbol{\Lambda}_k(\mathbf{x}_n - \boldsymbol{\mu}_k) = \mathbf{x}_n^\top \boldsymbol{\Lambda}_k \mathbf{x}_n - 2 \boldsymbol{\mu}_k^\top \boldsymbol{\Lambda}_k \mathbf{x}_n + \boldsymbol{\mu}_k^\top \boldsymbol{\Lambda}_k \boldsymbol{\mu}_k$$
Or is this the case when $\mathbf{x}_n$ comes from normal distribution, $\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{x}_n|\boldsymbol{\mu}_k,{\Lambda}_k)$ ?

I'm a bit confused because I know following equation is generally correct.
$$(\mathbf{x}_n - \boldsymbol{\alpha})^T (\mathbf{x}_n-\boldsymbol{\alpha}) = \mathbf{x}_n^T \mathbf{x}_n - \mathbf{x}_n^T \boldsymbol{\alpha} - \boldsymbol{\alpha}^T \mathbf{x}_n + \boldsymbol{\alpha}^T \boldsymbol{\alpha} $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement is true as long as the $\mathbf{\Lambda}_n$ matrix is symmetric.

Expand the product and you'll get:
$(\mathbf{x}_n -  \mathbf{\mu}_n)^T \mathbf{\Lambda}_n (\mathbf{x}_n -  \mathbf{\mu}_n) = \mathbf{x}_n ^T \mathbf{\Lambda}_n \mathbf{x}_n - \mathbf{x}_n^T \mathbf{\Lambda}_n \mathbf{\mu}_n -  \mathbf{\mu}_n^T \mathbf{\Lambda}_n \mathbf{x}_n + \mathbf{\mu}_n^T \mathbf{\Lambda}_n \mathbf{\mu}_n$

The cross terms are equal only if the lambda matrix is symmetric.